# Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I have a script that updates a text object, using a frame_change_post handler. The scene is imported as a strip in the VSE (for subtitling). It works fine but when I render the animation, it crashes after an inconstant amount of frames.

```
Append frame 57 Time: 00:00.37 (Saving: 00:00.11)

Append frame 58 Time: 00:00.38 (Saving: 00:00.12)

Append frame 59 Time: 00:00.40 (Saving: 00:00.12)

Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked

Current thread 0x00007f80aeccf800 (most recent call first):
File "/usr/share/blender/2.74/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 200 in <lambda>
File "/usr/share/blender/2.74/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 199 in modules
File "/usr/share/blender/2.74/scripts/startup/bl_ui/__init__.py", line 111 in addon_filter_items
File "/usr/share/blender/2.74/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_userpref.py", line 1237 in draw
Aborted
```

Looks like I am doing something wrong... here's the [code](https://github.com/Nikos-Prinios/blender-sub/blob/master/blend-sub.py) and, in case it's relevant, the script in [action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHjGF1g5gh8)

Comment: Consider using a more common python indentation practice (4 spaces, no tabs), even if you ignore all the rest of [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved the crash situation changing the handler from :

```
frame_change_post
```

to

```
frame_change_pre
```

Which makes sense...